# react-bootstrap Navbar is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` Navbar, but it's not working. No dropdowns are working, no collapsing is working. Don't know why.

```
import {Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap'


<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                  <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                      <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                  </Navbar.Header>
                  <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                      <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
                      </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
                      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                  </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
```

[image]

And dropdown list is hidden:
[image]

Don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Did you try to add the css file? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: CSS is showing properly. as you can see.

Comment: you need boostrap's js for these features + jquery + some code on your side. As far as I remember this is properly documented on the bootstrap website

Comment: I am using `react-bootstrap` - So i don't think that needs bootstrap.js

Comment: @NomanAli Can you share the version of react-bootstrap that you are using. And if upgrading to the latest version is option for you or not